# getting a specific String of unknown length from innerHTML

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to get a skuID which is found within a script within the html of a page (Of the form sku102921 with unknown length of numbers (could be sku219043012 or sku2131)).  I was thinking it would be good to use a regex.. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public String getRecommendedOfferSkuID() {
    WebElement recommendedOffer = driver.findElement(By.xpath"//td[@class='recomm-offer']"));
    String recommendedOfferHTML = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", recommendedOffer);
    java.lang.String skuID == "";
    recommendedOfferHTML.   //need help here
```

the script in the HTML has this method containing the skuID

```
submitFormByButtonId("prod9760999"+"-" + "sku30768633");
```

Comment: said that the text does not contain any ambiguous contents that may hit collisions with your intended search...then something like this regex may be enough: `(sku\d+)` ...it will just match the sku literal followed by any amount of digits. Of course you need to implement the Regex matching in Java. But that could be the expression you may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying this:

```
java.lang.String skuID = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("sku\\d+");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(recommendedOfferHTML);
while(m.find()) {
    skuID = m.group(1);
}
```

thanks for the input Diego